# Is it possible to run `cargo watch` in a workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
Foo
  Bar
  Baz
  Examples
```

Cargo.toml in `Foo/`

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "Bar",
    "Baz",
    "Examples",
]
```

Can I run `cargo watch build ???` in `Foo/`? So that if I change any file inside `Bar`, `Baz` or `Examples` it would trigger a rebuild?

Comment: I guess you should [file an issue](https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch/issues)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `cargo watch -x "build --all"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cargo watch -x "run -p Bar"    
cargo watch -x "run -p Baz"
```

and etc...